# Jump without jmp near

Tags: ida, disassembly, debugging, binary-analysis, program-analysis

I need to jump a

```
Hello,
```

I need to jump some lines that lock program in a loop status.
i use process hacker to find lines with string in binary but when i find this lines i have not jumps near, in fact i can't find CALL send me to this lines.

this is a part of code:

```
00AD06C8                         | 70 01                      | jo AD06CB                                       |
00AD06CA                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD06CC                         | 04 00                      | add al,0                                        |
00AD06CE                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD06D0                         | 2300                       | and eax,dword ptr ds:[eax]                      |
00AD06D2                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD06D4                         | 0D 00000000                | or eax,0                                        |
00AD06D9                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD06DB                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD06DD                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD06DF                         | 0090 01000000              | add byte ptr ds:[eax+1],dl                      |
00AD06E5                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD06E7                         | 0003                       | add byte ptr ds:[ebx],al                        |
00AD06E8                         | 0302                       | add eax,dword ptr ds:[edx]                      |
00AD06EA                         | 0122                       | add dword ptr ds:[edx],esp                      |
00AD06EC                         | 42                         | inc edx                                         |
00AD06ED                         | 0065 00                    | add byte ptr ss:[ebp],ah                        |
00AD06F0                         | 72 00                      | jb AD06F2                                       |
00AD06F2                         | 6C                         | insb                                            |
00AD06F3                         | 0069 00                    | add byte ptr ds:[ecx],ch                        |
00AD06F6                         | 6E                         | outsb                                           |
00AD06F7                         | 0020                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],ah                        |
00AD06F9                         | 0053 00                    | add byte ptr ds:[ebx],dl                        |
00AD06FC                         | 61                         | popad                                           |
00AD06FD                         | 006E 00                    | add byte ptr ds:[esi],ch                        |
00AD0700                         | 73 00                      | jae AD0702                                      |
00AD0702                         | 2000                       | and byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0704                         | 46                         | inc esi                                         |
00AD0705                         | 0042 00                    | add byte ptr ds:[edx],al                        |
00AD0708                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD070A                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD070C                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD070E                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0710                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0712                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0714                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0716                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0718                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD071A                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD071C                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD071E                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0720                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0722                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0724                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0726                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0728                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD072A                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD072C                         | 42                         | inc edx                                         |
00AD072D                         | 0065 00                    | add byte ptr ss:[ebp],ah                        |
00AD0730                         | 72 00                      | jb AD0732                                       |
00AD0732                         | 6C                         | insb                                            |
00AD0733                         | 0069 00                    | add byte ptr ds:[ecx],ch                        |
00AD0736                         | 6E                         | outsb                                           |
00AD0737                         | 0020                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],ah                        |
00AD0739                         | 0053 00                    | add byte ptr ds:[ebx],dl                        |
00AD073C                         | 61                         | popad                                           |
00AD073D                         | 006E 00                    | add byte ptr ds:[esi],ch                        |
00AD0740                         | 73 00                      | jae AD0742                                      |
00AD0742                         | 2000                       | and byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0744                         | 46                         | inc esi                                         |
00AD0745                         | 0042 00                    | add byte ptr ds:[edx],al                        |
00AD0748                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD074A                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD074C                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD074E                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0750                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0752                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0754                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0756                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0758                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD075A                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD075C                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD075E                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0760                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0762                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0764                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0766                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0768                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD076A                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD076C                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD076E                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0770                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0772                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0774                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0776                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0778                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD077A                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD077C                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD077E                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0780                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0782                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0784                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0786                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0788                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD078A                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD078C                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD078E                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0790                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0792                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0794                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0796                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD0798                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD079A                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD079C                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD079E                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD07A0                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD07A2                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD07A4                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD07A6                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD07A8                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD07AA                         | 0000                       | add byte ptr ds:[eax],al                        |
00AD07AC                         | 4E                         | dec esi                                         |
00AD07AD                         | 006F 00                    | add byte ptr ds:[edi],ch                        |
00AD07B0                         | 72 00                      | jb AD07B2                                       |
00AD07B2                         | 6D                         | insd                                            |
```

00AD06CC is the line that process hacker show problem.

as you can see error appears in different lines. 
[image]

Comment: can you please format the code so it does at least displays correctly? Currently it's hard to read.

Comment: yes sorry. edited

Comment: You are looking at the wrong place. This is clearly only *data*, and this disassembly means exactly nothing. You must find the location where that string gets used instead.

Comment: i have update a photo of odg32 stacks